# Error de casting int ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, casting

estoy usando VS 2017 para un tutorial pero me saca el error:
No se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo long en System.Web.MVC.ActionResult

¿Cómo se arregla eso?

El controlador

```
 public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    private TablaDato tabladato = new TablaDato();
    // GET: Default
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Convert.ToInt64(tabladato.Conteo());
    }
}
```

TablaDato.cs

```
  [Table("TablaDato")]
    public partial class TablaDato
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Relacion { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Valor { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }

        public int Orden { get; set; }

        public int Conteo() {
            using (var ctx = new contextoProyectoPortafolio())
            {
                return ctx.TablaDato.Count();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que en tu controlador regresas un tipo de dato `Int64` cuando deberías regresar un `ActionResult`. Para corregir el problema deberás regresar un `View` con el resultado de tus datos:

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    private TablaDato tabladato = new TablaDato();
    // GET: Default
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(Convert.ToInt64(tabladato.Conteo()));
    }
}
```

O, en su caso, un `json`, todo depende de lo que esperes en la vista:

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    private TablaDato tabladato = new TablaDato();
    // GET: Default
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Json(Convert.ToInt64(tabladato.Conteo()), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. Gracias Phi

Comment: @JhonHernández ¿fue de ayuda la respuesta?

Comment: Sí. Pude ejecutar el programa.